# Can I use ASP.NET Core targeting only .NET 4.6.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I heard that ASP.NET Core can target .NET Framework 4.6.1. Does that mean it can use only .NET 4.6.1, or it can use .NET 4.6.1 alongside with .NET Core?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can run ASP.NET Core on top of .NET Core 1.0, or .NET Framework 4.5.1+. Since "ASP.NET Core" is really just a set of NuGet packages, you can install them into a project targeting either framework.

For example, a .NET Core project would look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": { }
  }
```

While a .NET Framework project would look like (in the case of .NET 4.6.1):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  }
```

This works because the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc) package has targets for both .NET Framework 4.5.1 and .NET Standard Library 1.6.

It's also possible to build for both frameworks from one project:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In this case, note that the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency is moved *inside* of the `frameworks` section. This is necessary because this dependency is only needed when building for `netcoreapp1.0`, not `net461`.

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.0 won't be able to target the full .NET framework ([see github](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2022)), only .NET Core 2.0

Comment: Aaaaaaaand luckily, they changed their mind ([source](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/05/11/microsoft_asp_net_core_2_0/)).

Comment: And back again to unsupported with ASP.NET Core 3.0 ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/a-first-look-at-changes-coming-in-asp-net-core-3-0/))

Comment: This works, but I'm curious if anyone has actually gotten the "View" part of MVC working.  I'm not quite sure what mechanism compiles the Razor view files.  Posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58667252/is-it-possible-to-use-asp-net-core-2-x-mvc-on-net-framework-4-6-1-console-appli) on this.

Answer (score 4):

You can do both - i.e. target only desktop CLR, Core CLR or both. To target desktop Clr 4.6.1 use the `net461` moniker as target framework. To target Core Clr use `netcoreapp1.0`. You can use them side by side but it feels a bit awkward - why would you do even do that in case of apps?

Comment: Thanks. Some web hosting services are supporting only to .NET 4.6.1. So I want to use Asp.NET Core but still be able to deloy it on these services.

Comment: @AnyName Well, ASP.Net Core targeting desktop .NET is still Asp.NET Core. If you are not going to have separate code what's the point of cross compiling - just target net4x? On  the other hand there are actually two "flavours" of Asp.NET Core when targeting `netcoreapp1.0` - it can be a portable or standalone (i.e. seflcontained) app. If your provider does not support portable .NET Core apps create a standalone app - it is self contained (i.e. contains the runtime) so does not have any additional dependencies).

Comment: Does that mean I can't deploy the app if the provider doesn't support .NET Core (regardless of the targeted .NET)? Currently, I'm using shared host so there aren't so much options.

Comment: @AnyName if targeting netcoreapp1.0 and the shared runtime is not installed on the target machine you need to create a standalone/self-contained app. An alternative is to target net4x if .NET Framework is installed on the target host.