# Injectable RESTful service

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to get an idea on how to create a REST service that can be:

- Activated/Deactivated
- Injected into the software using DI

The first idea I had was using the WebAPI. After creating the controllers and models I wanted to integrate everything into our DI (we're using spring.NET), but I can't really get an idea on how I actually can invoke the REST service programatically. The `Global.axax`seems to be the first entrypoint, but it does not offer any methods to 'start' or 'stop' the service.

The second idea is, that I could be using WCF. That way I could inject the service as well as start/stop it. But on the otherhand am I under the impression that WCF is for SOAP and WebApi for REST. Is there any way to achieve my desires using WebAPI or should I go with WCF?

The project is using .Net Framework 4.6.1. So there is no chance to use cool features shipped with .Net Core.

Comment: When you talk about features can you enum them please ? are those specific to the technologie or to the framework ?

Comment: `WCF is for SOAP` is not correct. Any Rest services can be written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use WCF for REST Web service take a look [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide).

If you want all the features that you ask  all you can try ASP Core project with Framework 4.6 and even work with IIS  just take a look to the project creator you have this possibility.

here's some explication by [Nate Barbettini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38166777/2954082)

Comment: I'm probably going to use WCF for that, but still, WebAPI would be my first choice if possible. The reason for that is, that MS advised on using WebAPI for REST instead of WCF in this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-and-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: Yes i think it would be better to make a rest api with web api or asp core because there's  good features and better serializer also.