# Change an existing ASP.NET Core web app to target .NET Framework 4.x

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I wrote a web app using ASP.NET Core web app targeting .NET Core 2. 
I didn't realize GoDaddy does not support ASP.NET Core, but only ASP.NET Framework 4.x.

What are the steps I need to follow to migrate to support ASP.NET Framework?

Clear step-by-step explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Running ASP.NET Core apps on .NET Framework still requires ASP.NET Core Module to be installed on IIS. I assume GoDaddy does not support that either. So your simplest approach is to create an ASP.NET 4.x project and move useful code into it.

Comment: @LexLi But according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166724/can-i-use-asp-net-core-targeting-only-net-4-6-1 `"ASP.NET Core" is really just a set of NuGet packages` Can you please help me understand?

Comment: I won't help you understand that, as you can learn from experiments and Microsoft Docs to see the truth.

Comment: Do you have to use GoDaddy? how about moving to Azure or another hosting provider that supports ASP.Net Core

Comment: Hosting really shouldn't dictate your development choice as it's such a commodity and easy to change (unless you're locked into a plan).  An alternative could be [A2 Hosting](https://www.a2hosting.com/windows-hosting/core).

Comment: @MarkG Thanks. Do you have experience with A2Hosting?

Comment: @DonBox I haven't I just read a summary at [5 Best ASP.NET Hosting Providers](https://hostingpill.com/asp-net-hosting/).  Choosing a hosting company is so subjective so I recommending reading [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Comment: @DonBox If your hosting provider doesn't support ASP.NET Core, you only have 2 solutions. Downgrade to previous ASP.NET version or change hosting provider that support .NET Core. Please kindly check this blog https://windowswebhostingreview.com/looking-for-asp-net-core-2-hosting-try-this-provider/ if you need .NET Core hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have built the app, source a hosting provider that will host it, eg Microsoft Azure. The app is built using a modern technology there is no need to rebuilt it something else (arguably less modern) and the cost of re-building it will outweigh the hosting costs, ie you can host today and continue development.