# Is it possible to use ASP.NET Core 2.x MVC on .NET Framework 4.6.1 console application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm attempting to port an ASP.NET MVC 4.x application over to ASP.NET Core 2.2.  WebApi works great, but I'm stuck with porting over the MVC views.  I've created a full "minimally viable" repro to show what I mean.  The Program.cs looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string port = "9005";

            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls($"http://0.0.0.0:{port}")
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddMvcCore()
                .AddRazorViewEngine()
                .AddJsonFormatters();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

I have one controller in Controllers\HomeController.cs that looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I have one view at Views\Home\Index.cshtml that looks like this:

```
@{
    var x = "Test";
}

Home page
```

When I run the program, I can confirm I hit the breakpoint at `return View();` - I get no exceptions or anything.  However, the browser will return an error 500 and nothing is displayed.

My theory is I'm missing whatever the mechanism is that compiles the Index.cshtml into something the ASP.NET Core MVC framework can find.  I've done a bit of research but it's very unclear how all this works.  There is something called `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` which apparently does runtime compilation of cshtml files, but it has a .NET Core dependency.  In the ASP.NET 4.x world, I believe there was an ASP.NET compiler that would run as a build target that handled this sort of thing, but it's a bit unclear how it works.  Pretty much every Visual Studio template for ASP.NET Core is built around .NET Core, which seems to magically make this stuff work but I'm not exactly sure how.  Anyone know what the next steps would be to get this to work?  Thanks!

**PS:** The reason I cannot run on the .NET Core framework is because this project has a massive amount of dependencies on legacy .NET Framework (Windows) code which would take years to port over.

**Edit:** Here's my entire CSPROJ file (I've tried a few SDKs to no avail)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your project targes .NET Framework you should install [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation/) package.

It contains build-time references required to enable Razor view compilation.

Include its package reference to your `.csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

**This extra step is only aplicable on .net core project targets**

Execute the below command at the project root to prepare the app for a [framework-dependent deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd):

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

Comment: I installed the package, but it still doesn't work.  If I run `ildasm` on the EXE, I don't see anything in the Views namespace so I don't think anything got compiled.  Do I need to add anything to the CSPROJ to actually tell it to compile those files?  Or, is there an SDK I can use on the <Project> that does this for me?  Thanks!

Comment: I found some help in [this article](https://softwareproduction.eu/2018/02/12/asp-net-core-precompiled-razor-views-class-library/) as well - basically I had to put a `<Target Name="PrecompileRazorViews" AfterTargets="Build" DependsOnTargets="MvcRazorPrecompile" /> ` in my CSPROJ file, then some stuff to copy over the DLL to the output directory.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Thank you so much for the bounty.